# lstd++ & extern - calling C++ from C

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have wrapped my C++ header file in an extern "C" block to allow calling C++ functions from C. I have included the proper header files in the proper places. It works if I do something like the following:

```
g++ -c cpp_src.cc
gcc -c c_src.c
gcc -o c_exe c_src.o cpp_src.o -lstdc++
```

But if I remove the -lstdc++ from the last line, I get a bunch of errors. Because of reasons beyond my control, I cannot add the -lstdc++ flag. Is there a way to get the above to work without -lstdc++? What exactly is lstdc++, as in how does the gcc use it while linking with g++ compiled code?

Also, cpp_src.cc uses STL, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is placing unrealistic requirements on solutions...  Must use C++ but cannot link C++ libraries.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer If you don't want to answer it then don't, but don't abuse your closevote privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It's weird, but evidently it's an interesting real life situation: he can't change the build scripts. In his case it's for college, but for others it might be because the CM is away at holiday and unavailable, and they don't have access, but they still need to test or deploy stuff on the build server.

Comment: @YamMarcovic: If you buy a diesel car, you cannot use woodchips to power it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* need to have an object file that you can link with gcc without using -lstdc++, you can do an incremental link of your C++ object file with -lstdc++ and then use the result of that on your gcc link line.  Something like:

```
ld -i -static cpp_src.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -lstdc++ -o cpp_withstdlib.o
```

This will link your C++ object file with the standard C++ library and produce a new object file (`cpp_withstdlib.o`) that contains all the standard C++ library stuff you need, so can be linked on the gcc command line without needing `-lstdc++`

The tricky part is the `-L` option -- you need to figure out where g++ has stashed its standard library, as it generally doesn't put it in the standard `/usr/lib` location.  The above is for an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  On most Linux machines, you can find it with `locate libstdc++.a`

You're generally just better off using `g++` to link C++ code, as it knows all the right paths and won't make little mistakes that result in a binary that superficially appears to work, but is actually incorrect.

---

Using Josh's suggestion, you can do:

```
ld -i -static cpp_src.o `g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.a` -o cpp_withstdlib.o
```

which is a bit cleaner, and could readily be done in a Makefile.

Comment: Classy! (And someone's going to flame me in 3..2..1..)

Comment: You can find the location of libstdc++.a with '`g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.a`'.  Credit goes to http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc.

Answer (score 2):

`-lstdc++` causes the linker to link to `libstdc++`, which is gcc's implementation of the C++ standard library. If your code uses any symbols from the standard library (it uses the standard library, and not all code is inlined from headers), it must link `libstdc++` (or whichever standard library implementation you use).

You can avoid the standard library, or you can link against the system standard library, or you can statically link a copy of the standard library into your program.

Comment: Its actually the standard C++ library, with all the stuff in the `std::` namespace.  STL is only a small part of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't avoid the STL; "you can statically link a copy of the STL into your program" - that seems promising. Any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: You still need to use the `-l` to statically link.  You must refer to that library at some point to either dynamically reference the functions or import them directly into your binary.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I can change the first line, where I am compiling with g++, but not the 2nd and 3rd 'gcc' lines.

Comment: This seems like a really weird restriction that you seem unwilling to explain.  Either stop using STL functions, rewrite the CPP code as straight C code or link to libstd++

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Not even that. A small part of the standard library was _based on_ the STL but they are still not one and the same.

Comment: The restriction is due to my professor who is unwilling to listen to reason. The gcc lines are part of an automated system that he is unwilling to change for a single student. Hopefully, showing him this page would help change his mind.

Comment: @user5527407 if your assignment was to implement something in pure `c` you should have adhered to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's the thing: C++ (including STL) was allowed. Apparently the professor was under the impression that the automated test-cases could be linked to my C++ code without making any changes to his makefile.

Comment: "If your code uses any symbols from the standard library [...], it must link libstdc++" -- Technically wrong. He can provide the symbols himself. If there aren't that many of them, it's actually a plausible hacked solution.

Comment: @user5527407, it's not impossible that the professor is correct. Most implementations link their version of the standard library implicitly.

Comment: @user5527407 Your professor: is he using clang or gcc?

Comment: @StoryTeller True, but his professor is probably compiling with `gcc` which doesn't link C++'s standard library implementation.

Comment: Your professor says C++ is allowed, yet only links using the `gcc` **C** compiler?  And won't allow linking in the C++ libraries *required* to run C++ code?  Wow.  If that's correct, that demonstrates a complete lack of understanding about the subject he's selling himself as an expert in.  That's literally just one step removed from allowing you to use C++ code but not allowing you to use a C++ compiler.